# Hibernate transaction and physical transactions starts and close at the same time?

Tags: database, hibernate, transactions

When I start a hibernate transaction does it open a connection to database and start a physical connection there? The question is the same for closing a hibernate transaction so does it close the physical transaction immediately?

Thanks!

Comment: could you post the code between session instanciation and commit transaction?

Answer (score 2):

No. It uses a connection pool, as described in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-hibernatejdbc). So connections are retrieved from a pool, and, when closed, they simply go back to the pool.

Comment: OK, but what about the transactions?

Comment: In a non-JTA environment, a Hibernate transaction corresponds the a JDBC transaction.